# Python decision tree classification of complex objects

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I have a collection of clothing / accessory products (represented by a Python object) with various attributes. These products are generated by a combination of querying an external API and scraping the merchant websites to obtain various attributes.

My goal is to develop a classifier that uses these attributes to correctly categorise the products (i.e. into categories such as trousers, t-shirts, dresses etc.).

I have both a training and a test data set which are a subset of the entire data set selected uniformly at random which have been manually categorised.

I spoke to an ex-university colleague of mine who specialises in machine learning and he suggested using a decision tree. However, the decision tree libraries in Python appear to be very numerically focused (rather than focused on classifying data based on textual attributes).

I am aware of libraries like [Scikit Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) but from my brief analysis it appears that they generally involve simpler logic for the rules than I require.

Any suggestions on approach, library, code structure etc would be greatly appreciated. However, the main focus of this question is **which Python machine learning library (if any) would be most appropriate for this task**.

The product attributes include the following:

- name (`str`)
- description (`str`)
- available_sizes (`[str, str...]`)
- available_colours ([str, str...])
- price (`float`)
- url (`str`)
- category_name (`str`)
- images (`[str, str...]` - urls)

An example of a product:

```
{   'category': u"Men's Accessories",
    'colours': [u'White'],
    'description': u'Keep your formal style looking classic with this white short sleeve Oxford shirt with roll up sleeve detailing.',
    'ean': u'',
    'gender': u'M',
    'images': [   u'http://media.topman.com/wcsstore/TopMan/images/catalog/83D21DWHT_large.jpg',
                  u'http://media.topman.com/wcsstore/TopMan/images/catalog/83D21DWHT_2_large.jpg',
                  u'http://media.topman.com/wcsstore/TopMan/images/catalog/83D21DWHT_3_large.jpg',
                  u'http://media.topman.com/wcsstore/TopMan/images/catalog/83D21DWHT_4_large.jpg'],
    'last_scraped': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 1, 7, 13, 28, 943000),
    'merchant_id': 2479L,
    'merchant_uri': u'http://www.topman.com/en/tmuk/product/white-oxford-short-sleeve-shirt-157702?geoip=noredirect',
    'name': u'White Oxford Short Sleeve Shirt',
    'price': 26.0,
    'sizes': [u'XXS', u'XS', u'S', u'M', u'L', u'XL', u'XXL']}
```

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your goal, but OpenCV has some machine learning classifiers: See chpt 13 from: http://www.cs.haifa.ac.il/~dkeren/ip/OReilly-LearningOpenCV.pdf In parituclar, see the section on binary decision trees on pg 486; the poisonous mushroom eg may be a helpful model. The egs are in C, but the code can easily be modified to run in python

Comment: Could you briefly explain what it exactly is that you want to achieve with that classifier? Is it finding a mapping between the user entered category and an actual product in your database?

Comment: @tttthomasssss I have product data coming from an external API which is entered manually by users of the other system. The quality of the categorisation is appalling so I need to develop a system that assigns products to the correct internal category based on the products attributes.

Comment: I have updated the post to add more information due to the questions, down-votes and votes to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scikit-learn, but you need to preprocess your data. Other implementations of decision trees can deal with categorical data directly, that will not solve your problems however. You still need to preprocess the data.

First, I would leave out the images, as using them is somewhat complex.
For all the other variables, you need to encode them in a way that is sensible for machine learning. For example the available sizes could be encoded as a 0 or 1 depending on whether a given size is available.
The colors could be encoded as a categorical if they come from a fixed set of strings. If this is a free text field, using a categorical might not be great (for example people might be using gray and grey, which would be two completely unrelated values, or have typos, etc.)

The descriptions and names are probably unique to each product, so using categorical variables there doesn't make sense, as each one will only be seen once. For these it would probably be best to encode them using a bag of word approach.

You can find a tutorial on text classification in the [tutorials section of the scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/tutorial/index.html). You might want to have a look a the other tutorials, too.

Finally, I would suggest starting with a linear classifier, like Naive Bayes or LinearSVC. Single trees are mostly useful if you want to extract the actual rules, and are rarely used in text processing afaik (there are often tens or hundreds of thousands of features / word, so extracting meaningful rules is hard). If you want to use a tree-based method, using an ensemble like a random forest or gradient boosting will most likely yield better results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I picked up an ebook copy of Learning scikit-learn: Machine Learning in Python which goes into some detail about feature extraction and I am going to attempt a Naive Bayes classifier I think.

Comment: Not sure that is the best resource. There is also this one, whose authors I trust a deal more: http://www.amazon.com/Building-Learning-Community-Experience-Distilled/dp/1782161406
I started proof-reading the one you have for packt, but gave up as there were too many factual errors. The website tutorials should actually be pretty good resources.

Comment: That is interesting, I'll take a look at your suggestion once I've finished this. The key leap that Learning scikit-learn enabled was connecting my previous experience in ML with OpenCV which involved a lot of complex feature extraction with the idea of extracting features from textual data.

Comment: I'm unsure about how one goes about applying different forms of feature extraction to different attributes. For example it would be useful to use [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) vectorise the name and description attributes but the [`DictVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer) looks more appropriate for the other attributes.

Comment: At the moment, there is no standard way to do this afaik. There was a snipplet about that on the mailing list but I can't find it any more. Basically you have to extract the different features, map them and stack them again. If you want to build a scikit-learn pipeline for it, you can do if using FeatureUnion, but you have to provide your own estimator that extracts the keys for each transformation.

Comment: Thanks :) [The example in the comments](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2034#issuecomment-25317009) seems to give a pretty comprehensive and concise example of how it can be achieved.

Comment: The `GetItemTransformer` is seriously incomplete and I'm having a hard time working out how to fix it. Can you give me some pointers?

Comment: You need to be more specific than that for a helpful reply. Btw, you might also want to look at the example in this pull request: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/3680

Comment: Yeah I thought it might be a a little wishy washy. The issue is that the transformer is receiving a list of dictionaries where I was expecting it to receive a single dict from the comments on that issue.

Comment: That sounds different from what you posted in your original question. So all data points are in a single dict? What are then the keys and what the values?

Comment: They keys are the feature names (i.e. name, description etc) and the values are the values for that feature. I have the following: `[{'name': 'foo',…"}, {'name': 'bar',…"},…]` which is all of the training data.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you for a second. You are right, you need to transform your data. If all data points have the same keys, you can do

```data_dict = {}
for key in data[0].keys():
    data_dict[key] = [item[key] for item in data]```

Comment: Thanks for that, I figured that issue out. Currently my issue now is that although I have a reasonably accurate classifier (91%) looking at the test data that is being misclassified there are some obvious areas where my supervision would aid the classifier's accuracy.i.e. one of the features is gender (-1 for male, 0 for missing and +1 for female) and some products are being miss classified as belonging to female tops despite their gender being male. How can I add simple rules like this to a my pipeline?

Comment: You can't generally add rules, but you could upweight that feature in the feature union (might not have an effect depending on the classifier). Generally it should just get picked up by the classifier, though. What classifier are you using?

Comment: I'm using `LinierSVC`. Now the main issue appears to be the `TfidfVectorizer` as the majority of the misclassifications are T-shirts vs Shirts which presumably means that "t-shirt" and "shirt" are not being treated as separate entities (although the accuracy is at 91.75% so perhaps not). Do you have any suggestions re shirt vs t-shirt? (again a massive thank you for all your help, you're a life saver)

Comment: Have a look at the ``TfidfVectorizer``'s ``vocabulary_`` attribute to see how shirt and t-shirt are treated.
You can also use the ``build_analyzer`` function:
``vec = TfidfVectorizer()
> [u't-shirt', u'shirt'] 
ana = vec.build_analyzer()
ana("T-shirt shirt")``
>> [u'shirt', u'shirt']
vec2 = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w[[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\\b')
ana = vec2.build_analyzer()
ana("T-shirt shirt")

Comment: Or with proper formating: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/amueller/85035b943363dbea0ced