# Merge numeric and text features for category classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to classify product items in order to predict their category based on the product title and their base price.

An example(product title, price, category):

```
['notebook sony vaio vgn-z770td dockstation', 3000.0, u'MLA54559']
```

Previously I was only using product title for the prediction task but I'd like to include the price to see if the accuracy improves.

The problem with my code is that I can't merge the text/numeric features, I've been reading some questions here in SO and this is my code excerpt:

```
#extracting features from text
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform([e[0] for e in training_set])
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

#extracting numerical features
X_train_price = np.array([e[1] for e in training_set])

X = sparse.hstack([X_train_tfidf, X_train_price]) #this is where the problem begins

clf = svm.LinearSVC().fit(X, [e[2] for e in training_set])
```

I try to merge the data types with sparse.hstack but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions
```

I guess the problem lies in X_train_price(a list of prices) but I don't know how to format it for the sparse function to succesfully work.

These are the shapes of both arrays:

```
>>> X_train_tfidf.shape
(65845, 23136)
>>>X_train_price.shape
(65845,)
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer here for a related issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712080/python-decision-tree-classification-of-complex-objects

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like this should be as simple as stacking the arrays. If scikit-learn follows the conventions I'm familiar with, then each row in `X_train_tfidf` is a training datapoint, and there are a total of 65845 points. So you just have to do an `hstack` -- as you said you tried to do.

However, you need to make sure the dimensions are compatible! In vanilla `numpy` you get this error otherwise:

```
>>> a = numpy.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)
>>> b = numpy.arange(15, 20)
>>> numpy.hstack((a, b))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/
        Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 270, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(map(atleast_1d,tup),1)
ValueError: arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Reshape `b` to have the correct dimensions -- noting that a 1-d array of shape `(5,)` is *totally different* from a 2-d array of shape `(5, 1)`.

```
>>> b
array([15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
>>> b.reshape(5, 1)
array([[15],
       [16],
       [17],
       [18],
       [19]])
>>> numpy.hstack((a, b.reshape(5, 1)))
array([[ 0,  1,  2, 15],
       [ 3,  4,  5, 16],
       [ 6,  7,  8, 17],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 18],
       [12, 13, 14, 19]])
```

So in your case, you want an array of shape `(65845, 1)` instead of `(65845,)`. I might be missing something because you are using *sparse* arrays. Nonetheless, the principle ought be the same. I have no idea what sparse format you're using based on the above code, so I just picked one to test:

```
>>> a = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(numpy.arange(15).reshape(5, 3))
>>> scipy.sparse.hstack((a, b.reshape(5, 1))).toarray()
array([[ 0,  1,  2, 15],
       [ 3,  4,  5, 16],
       [ 6,  7,  8, 17],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 18],
       [12, 13, 14, 19]])
```